# how to get value from array in array in array?

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

I get this array when I `print_r($_POST)`, from the below result I want to get the value of `skin`.

```
[skin] => 1.jpg
```

how will i do that ???

```
 Array
    (
        [form_key] => WceDMPJOQD17ZeSW
        [config_state] => Array
            (
                [themeoptions_general] => 1
            )

        [groups] => Array
            (
                [general] => Array
                    (
                        [fields] => Array
                            (
                                [themeoptions_images] => Array
                                    (
                                        [skin] => 1.jpg
                                    )

                                [themeoptions_customcss] => Array
                                    (
                                        [value] => color:#333;
                                    )

                            )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$arr['groups']['general']['fields']['themeoptions_images']['skin']`

Comment: btw `$arr` might be needed to be replaced with `$_POST` in your case... also look into your the `@` so you can add it infront to avoid the ugly errors when it's not defined...http://thesmithfam.org/blog/2006/05/07/php-the-operator/

Comment: This is not relevantly related to Magento though and could probably be called a too easy question :-s

Comment: it was related to a rendrer in magento dea Lucasmus, and sometimes too easy things make life hell :)

Comment: @lucas I agree, this never help anyone else as it's fundamental and very basic scripting knowledge, besides, `$_POST` in deep array is not the very best practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$_POST['groups']['general']['fields']['themeoptions_images']['skin']
```

This will give you the value of skin.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $_POST['groups']['general']['fields']['themeoptions_images']['skin']
```

prints

```
1.jpg
```