# How to get values from an array

Tags: php

I have a procedure running that tests an email address and then confirms it.

It returns an array it seems. But I cannot seem to get the 1 or 0 value from the array success field.
How can I get the value from the array below:
`Array ( [result] => Array ( [query] => e [success] => 0 ) )`

Thank you in advance for the assistance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get value from array in array in array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7076618/how-to-get-value-from-array-in-array-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for success

```
$array["result"]["success"];
```

for query

```
$array["result"]["query"];
```